# Cordova don't run onResume after Cordova Activity was destroyed

Tags: android, cordova

My app is a Cordova app which uses the barcode scanner plugin.

I am on MacOS, Cordova Android 6.1.2, barcode-scanner-plugin 6.0.6.

Some users complained that there is a problem when they use the app :

- the app starts
- they click on an img which launches the barcode scanner plugin
- on the barcode activity, they catch a QR Code. It's OK so far...
- then, the app tries to come back to the first screen and crashes

For those people, the problem is that Android, because of low memory detection, decided to destroy the Cordova activity.

Knowing that, I decided to use **onPause/onResume** Cordova events to handle this case.

But I face a problem, the **onResume** is not always called. When the Cordova activity is not destroyed, the onResume callback is well called. But when the Cordova activity is really destroyed (simulating it in configuring the "Don't keep activities" preference), then the onResume callback is not called!

My code :

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    if (console) {
      console.log("--> évènement document.ready (JQuery) lancé");
    }

    document.addEventListener("deviceready", function() {
      if (console) {
        console.log("--> évènement deviceready (Cordova) lancé");
      }

      document.addEventListener('pause', impots.scan.onPause, false);
      document.addEventListener('resume', impots.scan.onResume, false);
    }, false);
});


impots.scan.onPause = function() {
    console.log('Evenement pause ----------------');
    impots.scan.debugAppState()    
}

impots.scan.onResume = function(event) {
    console.log('Evenement resume ----------------');
    console.log('event ' + JSON.stringify(event));

    var storedState = window.localStorage.getItem(impots.scan.APP_STORAGE_KEY);

    // si storedState, c'est qu'Android a supprimé la Cordova Activity et il faut reconstituer l'UI
    if (storedState && storedState.SPI) {
        console.log('Chargement appStage a partir du LocalStorage')
        impots.scan.updateModel(storedState.SPI)
    }

    if (event.pendingResult) {
        if (event.pendingResult.pluginStatus === 'OK') {
            console.log('Recuperation d\'un QR code suite à la suppression de la Cordova activity')
            app.updateModel(event.pendingResult.result.text)
          } else {
            console.log('Probleme de réupération QR suite a la suppression de la Cordova activity')
        }
    }
    impots.scan.updateUI()
}
```

Log when the Cordova activity is not destroyed :

```
15:15:07.156 30876 30876 I CordovaLog: Changing log level to VERBOSE(2)
15:15:07.157 30876 30876 I CordovaActivity: Apache Cordova native platform version 6.1.2 is starting
15:15:07.157 30876 30876 D CordovaActivity: CordovaActivity.onCreate()
15:15:07.267 30876 30876 I chromium: [INFO:library_loader_hooks.cc(140)] Chromium logging enabled: level = 0, default verbosity = 0
15:15:07.456 30876 30903 W cr_BindingManager: Cannot setInForeground() - never saw a connection for the pid: 30876
15:15:07.516 30876 30876 D SystemWebViewEngine: CordovaWebView is running on device made by: asus
15:15:07.575 30876 30876 D CordovaActivity: Started the activity.
15:15:07.575 30876 30876 D CordovaActivity: Resumed the activity.
15:15:07.938 30876 30876 W cr_BindingManager: Cannot call determinedVisibility() - never saw a connection for the pid: 30876
15:15:08.915 30876 30876 I chromium: [INFO:CONSOLE(12)] "mobileinit event triggered, initialization...", source: file:///android_asset/www/impots/js/impots-override.js (12)
15:15:11.061 30876 30876 I chromium: [INFO:CONSOLE(49)] "--> évènement document.ready (JQuery) lancé", source: file:///android_asset/www/impots/js/impots.js (49)
15:15:11.575 30876 30876 I chromium: [INFO:CONSOLE(70)] "--> évènement deviceready (Cordova) lancé", source: file:///android_asset/www/impots/js/impots.js (70)
15:15:19.319 30876 30876 D CordovaActivity: Paused the activity.
15:15:19.399 30876 30876 W cr_Ime  : updateState: type [0->0], flags [0], show [false], 
15:15:19.403 30876 30876 I chromium: [INFO:CONSOLE(256)] "Evenement pause ----------------", source: file:///android_asset/www/impots/js/impots-scan.js (256)
15:15:19.403 30876 30876 I chromium: [INFO:CONSOLE(230)] "appState {}", source: file:///android_asset/www/impots/js/impots-scan.js (230)
15:15:19.404 30876 30876 I chromium: [INFO:CONSOLE(234)] "Stockage de l'appState en LocalStorage", source: file:///android_asset/www/impots/js/impots-scan.js (234)
15:15:19.565   187   187 W SurfaceFlinger: couldn't log to binary event log: overflow.
15:15:19.655   616  2208 W ActivityManager: Unable to start service Intent { cmp=com.google.android.apps.photos/.cameraassistant.CameraAssistantService (has extras) } U=0: not found
15:15:19.835   202   208 E ANDR-PERF-LOCK: Failed to apply optimization for resource: 4 level: 0
15:15:19.838   194   652 W Camera2-ZslProcessor3: ZslProcessor3: Unable to find the android.request.pipelineMaxDepth, use default pipeline max depth 4
15:15:20.737 30876 30876 D CordovaActivity: Stopped the activity.
15:15:22.381   616   632 W ActivityManager: Activity pause timeout for ActivityRecord{fa630ef u0 fr.gouv.finances.smartphone.android/com.google.zxing.client.android.CaptureActivity t250 f}
15:15:23.077   202   208 E ANDR-PERF-LOCK: Failed to reset optimization for resource: 4 level: 0
15:15:23.101 30876 30876 D CordovaActivity: Incoming Result. Request code = 195543262
15:15:23.102 30876 30876 D CordovaInterfaceImpl: Sending activity result to plugin
15:15:23.102 30876 30876 D BarcodeScanner: dans onActivityResult
15:15:23.104 30876 30876 D CordovaActivity: Started the activity.
15:15:23.104 30876 30876 D CordovaActivity: Resumed the activity.
15:15:23.251 30876 30876 I chromium: [INFO:CONSOLE(266)] "Evenement resume ----------------", source: file:///android_asset/www/impots/js/impots-scan.js (266)
15:15:23.251 30876 30876 I chromium: [INFO:CONSOLE(267)] "event {"isTrusted":false,"action":"resume"}", source: file:///android_asset/www/impots/js/impots-scan.js (267)
```

The resume event is well called.

When I use the "Don't keep activities" on the device and retry:

```
15:20:43.396  1144  1355 W OpenGLRenderer: Incorrectly called buildLayer on View: ShortcutAndWidgetContainer, destroying layer...
15:20:43.396  1144  1355 W OpenGLRenderer: Incorrectly called buildLayer on View: ShortcutAndWidgetContainer, destroying layer...
15:20:44.800  1672  1672 W System  : ClassLoader referenced unknown path: /data/app/fr.gouv.finances.smartphone.android-1/lib/arm
15:20:44.830  1672  1672 I CordovaLog: Changing log level to VERBOSE(2)
15:20:44.830  1672  1672 I CordovaActivity: Apache Cordova native platform version 6.1.2 is starting
15:20:44.830  1672  1672 D CordovaActivity: CordovaActivity.onCreate()
15:20:44.944  1672  1672 I chromium: [INFO:library_loader_hooks.cc(140)] Chromium logging enabled: level = 0, default verbosity = 0
15:20:45.160  1672  1703 W cr_BindingManager: Cannot setInForeground() - never saw a connection for the pid: 1672
15:20:45.221  1672  1672 D SystemWebViewEngine: CordovaWebView is running on device made by: asus
15:20:45.270  1672  1672 D CordovaActivity: Started the activity.
15:20:45.270  1672  1672 D CordovaActivity: Resumed the activity.
15:20:45.640  1672  1672 W cr_BindingManager: Cannot call determinedVisibility() - never saw a connection for the pid: 1672
15:20:46.605  1672  1672 I chromium: [INFO:CONSOLE(12)] "mobileinit event triggered, initialization...", source: file:///android_asset/www/impots/js/impots-override.js (12)
15:20:48.569  1672  1672 I chromium: [INFO:CONSOLE(49)] "--> évènement document.ready (JQuery) lancé", source: file:///android_asset/www/impots/js/impots.js (49)
15:20:49.026  1672  1672 I chromium: [INFO:CONSOLE(70)] "--> évènement deviceready (Cordova) lancé", source: file:///android_asset/www/impots/js/impots.js (70)
15:21:07.859  1672  1672 D CordovaActivity: Paused the activity.
15:21:07.929  1672  1672 W cr_Ime  : updateState: type [0->0], flags [0], show [false], 
15:21:07.940  1672  1672 I chromium: [INFO:CONSOLE(256)] "Evenement pause ----------------", source: file:///android_asset/www/impots/js/impots-scan.js (256)
15:21:07.943  1672  1672 I chromium: [INFO:CONSOLE(230)] "appState {}", source: file:///android_asset/www/impots/js/impots-scan.js (230)
15:21:07.943  1672  1672 I chromium: [INFO:CONSOLE(234)] "Stockage de l'appState en LocalStorage", source: file:///android_asset/www/impots/js/impots-scan.js (234)
15:21:08.103   187   187 W SurfaceFlinger: couldn't log to binary event log: overflow.
15:21:08.206   616  2094 W ActivityManager: Unable to start service Intent { cmp=com.google.android.apps.photos/.cameraassistant.CameraAssistantService (has extras) } U=0: not found
15:21:08.395   202   208 E ANDR-PERF-LOCK: Failed to apply optimization for resource: 4 level: 0
15:21:08.400   194  1102 W Camera2-ZslProcessor3: ZslProcessor3: Unable to find the android.request.pipelineMaxDepth, use default pipeline max depth 4
15:21:09.394  1672  1672 D CordovaActivity: Stopped the activity.
15:21:09.421  1672  1672 D CordovaActivity: CordovaActivity.onDestroy()
15:21:09.423  1672  1672 W cr_AwContents: WebView.destroy() called while WebView is still attached to window.
15:21:09.466  1672  1672 W cr_BindingManager: Cannot call determinedVisibility() - never saw a connection for the pid: 1672
15:21:09.468  1672  1672 W cr_AwContents: Application attempted to call on a destroyed WebView
15:21:09.468  1672  1672 W cr_AwContents: java.lang.Throwable
15:21:09.468  1672  1672 W cr_AwContents:   at org.chromium.android_webview.AwContents.isDestroyed(AwContents.java:1265)
15:21:09.468  1672  1672 W cr_AwContents:   at org.chromium.android_webview.AwContents.isDestroyedOrNoOperation(AwContents.java:1195)
15:21:09.468  1672  1672 W cr_AwContents:   at org.chromium.android_webview.AwContents.getTitle(AwContents.java:2063)
15:21:09.468  1672  1672 W cr_AwContents:   at org.chromium.android_webview.AwWebContentsDelegateAdapter.loadingStateChanged(AwWebContentsDelegateAdapter.java:280)
15:21:09.468  1672  1672 W cr_AwContents:   at org.chromium.base.SystemMessageHandler.nativeDoRunLoopOnce(Native Method)
15:21:09.468  1672  1672 W cr_AwContents:   at org.chromium.base.SystemMessageHandler.handleMessage(SystemMessageHandler.java:41)
15:21:09.468  1672  1672 W cr_AwContents:   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
15:21:09.468  1672  1672 W cr_AwContents:   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
15:21:09.468  1672  1672 W cr_AwContents:   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
15:21:09.468  1672  1672 W cr_AwContents:   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
15:21:09.468  1672  1672 W cr_AwContents:   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
15:21:09.468  1672  1672 W cr_AwContents:   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
15:21:09.469  1672  1703 W cr_BindingManager: Cannot setInForeground() - never saw a connection for the pid: 1672
15:21:16.298   616   632 W ActivityManager: Activity pause timeout for ActivityRecord{4e505a3 u0 fr.gouv.finances.smartphone.android/com.google.zxing.client.android.CaptureActivity t251 f}
15:21:16.747   202   208 E ANDR-PERF-LOCK: Failed to reset optimization for resource: 4 level: 0
15:21:16.774  1672  1672 I CordovaLog: Changing log level to VERBOSE(2)
15:21:16.774  1672  1672 I CordovaActivity: Apache Cordova native platform version 6.1.2 is starting
15:21:16.774  1672  1672 D CordovaActivity: CordovaActivity.onCreate()
15:21:16.781  1672  1703 W cr_BindingManager: Cannot setInForeground() - never saw a connection for the pid: 1672
15:21:16.799  1672  1672 D SystemWebViewEngine: CordovaWebView is running on device made by: asus
15:21:16.836  1672  1672 D CordovaActivity: Started the activity.
15:21:16.838  1672  1672 D CordovaActivity: Incoming Result. Request code = 195543262
15:21:16.839  1672  1672 D BarcodeScanner: dans onRestoreStateForActivityResult
15:21:16.839  1672  1672 D CordovaInterfaceImpl: Sending activity result to plugin
15:21:16.839  1672  1672 D BarcodeScanner: dans onActivityResult
15:21:16.839  1672  1672 D CordovaActivity: Resumed the activity.
15:21:17.147  1672  1672 W cr_BindingManager: Cannot call determinedVisibility() - never saw a connection for the pid: 1672
15:21:17.497  1672  1672 I chromium: [INFO:CONSOLE(12)] "mobileinit event triggered, initialization...", source: file:///android_asset/www/impots/js/impots-override.js (12)
15:21:17.954  1672  1672 I chromium: [INFO:CONSOLE(49)] "--> évènement document.ready (JQuery) lancé", source: file:///android_asset/www/impots/js/impots.js (49)
15:21:18.311  1672  1672 I chromium: [INFO:CONSOLE(70)] "--> évènement deviceready (Cordova) lancé", source: file:///android_asset/www/impots/js/impots.js (70)
```

This time the onResume is not called. However, I assume a result was found by the plugin because the log tells "CordovaActivity: Incoming Result. Request code = 195543262" and "CordovaInterfaceImpl: Sending activity result to plugin"

I see a problem though : "Application attempted to call on a destroyed WebView". It's just a warning but it can be the reason why the onResume is not called, I really don't figure out.

My CordovaActivity is like that :

```
public class MainActivity extends CordovaActivity
{
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        super.init();
        loadUrl(launchUrl);
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy()
    {
        super.onDestroy();
    }
}
```

Any idea would be appreciated!

Comment: did you ever find out the answer for this?